# Large image getting automatically scaled down to a blurry image on webpage

Tags: html, css

I've uploaded an image which is not blurry at all but once I display that image on the home page it looks like image 1 (very blurry). 
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRbSn.png)

The original image is not blurry at all. The graph was created in excel, I zoomed up real close, took a print scr (as opposed to snipping tool as with snipping tool it does get blurry) then put it in paint and cropped it out and saved it as a PNG.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Or if that is impossible, at least a link to the website where this happens, so we can look.

Comment: <p>
<a href="http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/portfolio-fund-performance/"><img src="http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/performance.png" alt="Performance graph" /></a>
</p>

If you click through to http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/performance.png (where the image is located) you can see it shouldn't get blurrier as it scales down.

Comment: Hm, if the problem is that the scaled-down words don't look as crisp as when you were to display a text in a smaller font size, I'd look into using svg for the image rather than png.

Comment: By the way, what browser are you testing with? I tested here with various browsers, but resizing the source image does not harm readability as badly as your screenshot shows. [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6hnar9c7/2/).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy with university finals.

Yep the problem is when it gets scaled down it's not as crisp. I'll look into svg and get back to you.

I'm currently testing with google chrome on a 1920x1080 monitor and I've tested it on lower resolution screens as well but they all come out blurry. 

Your fiddle shows up as blurry on my monitor as well (does it show up fine on yours? What resolution monitor are you using)

Answer (score -1):

If you put your image as it is and don't change the dimensions of your image, its's should looks fine (not blur). but if you change your image dimensions and force image to bigger than it's original size, it must be blur.

for more detail please mention your webpage link.

Comment: <p>
<a href="http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/portfolio-fund-performance/"><img src="http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/performance.png" alt="Performance graph" /></a>
</p>

If you click through to http://www.loftuspeak.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/performance.png (where the image is located) you can see it shouldn't get blurrier as it scales down.